# How to set up Firebase rules version 2 and getDocuments()

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am not sure how to solve this one.

I have collection and I would like to get all the documents with a certain condition

```
_firestore
    .collection('db')
    .where('userId', isEqualTo: userId)
    .getDocuments()
    .then(....
```

My firebase rule is as follow. I basically want to show to the user only the document with his userId

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

  match /bd/{checkin} {
    allow read: if resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid ;
  }
```

If I run I get the error of missing permission.

I understood that the issue is that I am using rule version 2. How would you write the firebase rule to allow for such query? Please note I would like to use version 2

Comment: Do you use fireAuth to login the user first?

Comment: Yes I do use firebase auth

Comment: I use the same rule just fine. I think  the problem is with something else. the only difference is with `where` condition, I use the way they are using in their documentation `.where('userId', '==', userId)`  If the problem still exists after trying the new `where` condition make sure that `userId` is correct

Comment: 1) On what platform are you running this code? Feel free to just add the tag to your question instead of answering btw, as that will also ensure the code gets highlighted correctly. 2) Can you add a statement that logs the value of `userId` right before this query, and then include the updated code and its output in your question? 3) Can you also show a screenshot of a document that should be returned by the query?

Comment: Oh dear , now it is working. I am using flutter! I am not sure why I have got the error but after a flutter clean and a flutter run I was able to get the data...